# Rails contact form `undefined method`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contact-form

I'm trying to build a contact form in Rails without storing the mails in my database. But I'm getting an `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` error when I send the form.

My MessagesController

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  if @message.valid?
    # TODO send message here
    Messages.new_messages_email(@mailer).deliver
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
  else
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Something went wrong, try again!"
  end
end

private
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(
    :name, 
    :message,
    :email
  )
end
```

My Messages model

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates :email, :email_format => {:message => 'is not looking good'}
  validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 500

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

The email body

```
!!!
%html
  %body
    %p
      = @mailer.name
      Schreef het volgende:
    %p= @mailer.message
    %p= @mailer.email
```

And in my routes I have

```
  resources :messages
```

I forgot to post my Messages mailer

```
class Messages < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "info@domein.nl"

    def new_messages_email(mailer)

    @mailer = mailer
    mail(to: 'peter@no-illusions.nl',
        subject: 'Iemand wilt contact met U')
    end
end
```

For completion my form,

```
= form_for @message do |f|
  .field
    %br/
    = f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Naam"
  .field
    %br/
    = f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Emailadres"
  .field
    %br/
    = f.text_area :message, :rows => 5, :placeholder => "Uw bericht"
  .actions= f.submit "Verstuur bericht", :id => "submit"
```

In my MessagesController I define the paramaters for the create function, but there's something I'm doing wrong, forgetting or overlooking which causes the error.

Comment: ` Messages.new_messages_email(@mailer).deliver` in this line you use `@mailer`, don't you mean `@message`, you've not defined `@mailer` unless it's elsewhere

Comment: Are you sure that you've got `form_for @message` in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller should be probably:

```
Messages.new_messages_email(@message).deliver # not @mailer
```

Besides that, you have to reinitialize `@message` within your mailer, e.g:

```
class Messages < ActionMailer::Base

  def new_messages_email(msg)
    @message = msg
  end

end
```

Comment: This is right answer, but you can just use  `@message = msg`.

Comment: Why `msg.id`? I'm not saving the message to a model, so there's no id for it. Using `Message.new` seems to fix it.

Comment: Peter, just do as @Зелёный suggested. I used to work with delayed mailers and they work slightly different.

Comment: Yup. Seem to have mixed up my naming along the way.